# How to login to SQL Server with AD users?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I have virtual server in a LAN that has Active Directory and some of the users are members of this domain. I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on this server. Then in the "Security > Logins", I created a new user that is AD user. But when that user wants to log in to SQL Sserver, an error occurs. What should I do?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on your server name object, select _Properties_, then in the resulting window select _Security_ in left-hand pane.  Then look in right-hand pane at the top, under _Server Authentication_, what mode is selected?

Comment: sql server and windows athentication

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  What is the exact error message?  Was the user you created a SQL user, or an AD user?  And when you received the error, how were you logging on, as the SQL or the AD user?